# How to exclude a regex match when I have comma without space after

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I have a regex working with 99% of my situations. But one is not working

My input is like that

```
MyString=[XXXXXX:XX   XX   XX   XX, XXXXX:332.83, XXXXX:XXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX, XXXX:0.0, XXXX:2, XXXX:0, XXXX:-256, XXXXX:5, XXXX:136935, XXXX:0, XXXX:XX XXX XXX, XXXX:0.5, XXXXX:true, XXXX:0.509375, XXX:0.0, [XXXX:2022-06-14 06:45:00], 2022-09-17,XXXXX:1]
```

This regex allows to match all `key:value` in between the first `[` and last `]`

```
(?<=(?<!: *)\[).*?(?=,)|(?<=, *(?=[^ \r\n]))(?:.*?(?=,)|[^,\r\n\[\]]+?(?=\])|[^,\r\n]+\](?= *\]))
```

It split all `key:value` when a comma is detected, but I have specific data where I have a comma without space after. For example, the last date of my example is split because of `,` I search to exclude this split match to match all `2022-09-17,XXXXX:1`

I search for a regex that match only data that a separate by `,`  and not `,`

Here is the example with the split of the last data I search to prevent
https://regex101.com/r/8fd7Xv/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a space, or 1 or more spaces at the positions that you assert a comma.

```
(?<=(?<!: *)\[).*?(?=, )|(?<=, +(?=[^ \r\n]))(?:.*?(?=, )|[^,\r\n\[\]]+?(?=\])|[^,\r\n]+\](?= *\]))
```

See the updated pattern https://regex101.com/r/Dlx8Xi/1

Comment: It not what I expect, I certainly didn't well explain. I search to include all 2022-09-17,XXXXX:1 in a match not have like previously a double match 2022-09-17 and XXXXX:1  because of comma

Comment: @Nitneuq So you don't want to exclude the comma like this? https://regex101.com/r/i48gGe/1